# JSON to Spring Controller

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I want to send a json with values from the form tag to a Spring MVC controller.

The forms on submit method executes the following code

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify($("#form1").serializeArray());  
    $.ajax({
        url :  "/DMS/webcontroller/startupload",
        type : "POST",
       // traditional : true,
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData:false,
        //dataType : "json",
        data : jsonStr,
        success : function (response) {
            alert('success ' + response);
        },
        error : function (response) {
            alert('error ' + response);
        },
    });
```

I have added the following to my spring configuration xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
     <property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>
```

My controller signature is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/startupload", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public @ResponseBody ReturnData startUpload(@RequestBody UploadStartVO startVO)
        {...
```

When I run this on tomcat 7 with firefox 31, I am getting the 415 response.If I check the request using tools I see that Content-Type has been added to the Request body. Also the 
Request data is query formatted like this:

```
supplierId=1111&unregSupplier=unregSupplier&customerName=customerName&externalEntity=externalentity&application=scms&logicalGroup=demand&user=u1&password=u1&appUser=appu1&documentType=email&documentDescription=documentDescription&contactPerson=contactPerson&contactNumber=contactNumber&documentGroupName=demand&documentPurpose=documentpurpose&uploaderIP=uploaderIp&uploaderName=scmsname&uploaderCompletePath=somepath%2Fsomepath&uploadDateTime=20%2F12%2F2014
```

and not like this:

```
[{"name":"supplierId","value":"1111"},{"name":"unregSupplier","value":"unregSupplier"},{"name":"customerName","value":"customerName"},{"name":"externalEntity","value":"externalentity"},{"name":"application","value":"scms"},{"name":"logicalGroup","value":"demand"},{"name":"user","value":"u1"},{"name":"password","value":"u1"},{"name":"appUser","value":"appu1"},{"name":"documentType","value":"email"},{"name":"documentDescription","value":"documentDescription"},{"name":"contactPerson","value":"contactPerson"},{"name":"contactNumber","value":"contactNumber"},{"name":"documentGroupName","value":"demand"},{"name":"documentPurpose","value":"documentpurpose"},{"name":"uploaderIP","value":"uploaderIp"},{"name":"uploaderName","value":"scmsname"},{"name":"uploaderCompletePath","value":"somepath/somepath"},{"name":"uploadDateTime","value":"20/12/2014"}]
```

Request Body shows :

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 457
```

Request header shows

```
Host: localhost:8082
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8082/DMS/
Cookie: JSESSIONID=C64F21EEECFC5BDF515C3DE22F51626A
Connection: keep-alive
```

If I edit this request and put the json(this is what is seen in the jsonStr var during debugging) in the request Body change the Content-Type in Body and add the Content-Type in the header I am getting a 400 Bad Request!!

Please help me with this!

EDIT::
So main problem is that $.ajax() is not creating proper request. Data is not json and contenttype is not application/json.

EDIT::
forgot to paste the pom.xml dependancy

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

EDIT:::
I tried the code with removing the Converted objects UploadStartVO and ReturnData and replacing with String object. The call was successful, the ajax() method still returned the exception but the form tag had the action attribute which goes properly to my controller method. Can anyone point out why the ajax call doesnt work?? Firefox 31

Comment: pls try with my answer, if it helps you

Comment: which version of spring you are using?

Comment: 4.0.2.RELEASE.jackson 2.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was sending data in the wrong format to the controller. I tried changing everything one by one. 
The controller header `headers = {"Content-type=application/json"}` was unrequired.

The `consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in the controller was not needed.

I downgraded from 2.3.3 to 1.9.1 the jackson version. That had no effect.

The data I sent initially was

```
 JSON.stringify({'key': 'John', 'application': 'SCMS'})
```

After changing it to

```
JSON.stringify({key: 'John', application: 'SCMS'})
```

The Request is not converted to the POJO properly.

Hope this saves someone some time!

Answer (score 0):

Try using below

Just try some below points if still not works.

1.) Try commenting/uncommenting combination of `contentType` and `dataType`.

2.) Also try using 'data : JSON.stringify(jsonStr),'.

3.) Also try to alert your data.

```
var jsonStr = $("#form1").serialize();  
    $.ajax({
        url :  "/DMS/webcontroller/startupload",
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        data : JSON.stringify(jsonStr),
        success : function (response) {
            alert('success ' + response);
        },
        error : function (response) {
            alert('error ' + response);
        },
    });
```

Comment: done all three! alert is what i see in the debugging. stringify in the value for data is still giving the error. I have also added the contenttype header in edit request.

Comment: Befor the request...Yes it does. I have pasted it in my q

Answer (score 0):

In Spring MVC , to output JSON data,you have to add `Jackson library` in the project classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: have added the dependency but hadnt pasted the pom.. version is 2.3.3

Comment: @kavita try removing `consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`, `@RequestBody` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Try with changing the code consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE with consumes="application/json"
Do the same for produces if it gives errors to the response too.
Eventually if it doesn't works try removing on the clientside code, in the header declaration the charset encoding, leaving just the application/json declaration.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.